# GPIO pin Status

Tags: rpi.gpio

Is it possible to know if there is something plugged on the pins ?

I made a web interface to control the Raspberry pi 3 remotely and I want to activate the pin where the relay is pluged but I don't have a direct access to the Pi. 
So I would like to know if it is possible to execute a command line or to run a python script and get the good pin.

PS: Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically conceivable that a GPIO pin switched to input behaves differently whether it is open (nothing is connected there) to a pin where a relay driving circuit (e.g. a transistor or optocoupler) is connected to. However I'd advise against it. First and formost because that discrimination would be relying upon the *floating* (open) pin (and its per definition random behaviour) vs. a pin connected to something. See [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/raspberry-pi-gpio-input-pins-give-random-values/14693#14693).

To be honest I do not understand the need to do so. Connecting the relay to the Pi implies knowledge to which pin it is connected. Why not just use that knowledge?

Comment: The fact is that it's not going to be me who will plug the pin and they will be more than one relay connected to the Raspberry.

Comment: In that case I'd still follow a deterministic approach. Whoever plugs one or more relays in, could determine which pins are used. Put that info in a config file used in your script/program.