# GPIO pin input goes high and low continuously

Tags: gpio

When I set GPIO pin for input and read the value, I get high and low continuously. Doesn't matter which pin I set. I couldn't even light a led yet.

This is happening when I connect 40 pin ribbon connector cable. Everything turns normal when I don't connect it. What is the reason? Is it cable?

Edit: I changed side of the cable and added some pictures. Still same. I also tried with PUD_DOWN. This time it is stable 0 but I have no movement input what so ever.

Second edit: Okay, My breadboard has two seperate part on power and ground lines. As you can see from picture I am trying to get ground and power from other side which is not connected to raspberry pi :)  So problem solved thanks everybody.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We will need to see pics of all the connections and the code you are using. However, the first thing I would suspect is that you have the ribbon cable installed backwards. The colored stripe goes at the end of the board closest to the SD card.

Comment: If there's nothing attached to the input and you read it, you're reading a [floating pin](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/raspberry-pi-gpio-input-pins-give-random-values/14693#14693) which has no fixed value. I'm not completely sure that's what's happening, as I can't see your connections. How's everything hooked up?

Comment: Actually I am trying to get an input from pir sensor. At first I thought I was getting this high and low value from sensor but It turns out If I change it to empty pin it does the same thing with same pattern. I have tried pull down. Yeah it makes the pin stable 0 but this time I don't get any input from pir sensor. I will share pic and code when I go home.

Comment: added some pictures of my pin setup. Changed side of the cable as you said.

Answer (score 2):

GPIO inputs are floating (varying between 0 and 1) until a known voltage is applied.

Radio interference on the ribbon cable will generate lots of spurious activity.

You need to set a default voltage on the GPIO.  The simplest way is to enable the internal pull-up or pull-down.  With a pull-up the GPIO should be stable as 1, with a pull-down the GPIO should be stable as a 0.

You can use the wiringPi gpio utility to set the default pulls (see its documentation).

My [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) utility also lets you set the pulls.

See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PUD

```
pigs pud 4 d # set internal pull-down on GPIO4

pigs pud 4 u # set internal pull-up on GPIO4

pigs pud 4 o # switch off internal pulls on GPIO4
```

Comment: Joan doesn't the fact that after removing the ribbon cable it works as expected argue against this as the cause?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I suppose so.  The ribbon cable acts as an aerial which makes the problem much more visible.  Without the cable a GPIO might be stable for hours, with a cable you can get hundreds of level changes a second.

Comment: GPIO inputs are **NOT** floating; as you well know the default state for all pins has a [pull](http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs). However connecting an antenna to the high impedance input will often override the pull.

Comment: @Milliways The pulls can be switched off by software, the defaults apply at power-up.

Comment: Actually I am trying to get an input from pir sensor. At first I thought I was getting this high and low value from sensor but It turns out If I change it to empty pin it does the same thing with same pattern. 

I have tried pull down. Yeah it makes the pin stable 0 but this time I don't get any input from pir sensor. I will share pic and code when I go home.

Comment: @hunterTR I am having the exact same problem. I also have exactly the same arrangement, have you found a solution? Did this answer worked as expected?

Comment: @ChristosK. I put it in the main post as second edit. It was pretty stupid but here is the answer :)
Second edit: Okay, My breadboard has two seperate part on power and ground lines. As you can see from picture I am trying to get ground and power from other side which is not connected to raspberry pi :) So problem solved thanks everybody.