# Activating Pull-down Resistors in C#

Tags: gpio, windows-iot, c#

I am facing exact same problem as asked here in [this question.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14680) It's basically the "*reading floating values*" problem when pull-down resistors are not used.

I am unable to activate pull-down resistors through C# code.I tried various [GpioPinDriveMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopindrivemode) input modes and the following code, but none of them solved my problem. I still got random inputs from the GPIO pin.

```
pin.SetDriveMode(GpioDriveMode.InputPullDown);
```

Is this the wrong way to activate pull-down resistors? How do I do that?

Note that the problem is solved when I physically add a resistor in series. However I would like to use the inbuilt pull-down resistors available in R'pi.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I made a silly mistake on my part. Visual studio was running my old source even after I rebuilt then deployed it. I had to clean my solution and then run it, and It turned out to be Okay!

```
pin.SetDriveMode(GpioDriveMode.InputPullDown);
```

This line is definitely the correct way to activate pull-down resistors using C#.